# When I want to upload image in windows os with adonis js I found this problem how can I solved this

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, adonis.js

EBUSY: resource busy or locked, copyfile 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ab-4da7f2e2-3f04-4c93-a453-0a71e1304435.tmp' -> 'F:\nipu\eCommerce\public\images\books\1575106014388.jpeg'

my code is here .....

```
    const coverImages = request.file('cover_images', {
    types: ['image'],
    size: '2mb'
  })

  const uploadFolder = Helpers.publicPath('/images/books')
  const filePaths = [];

  if(coverImages !== null && coverImages.files.length === 3 ){
    //Temporary
      //filePaths.push(`images/books/default.jpg`);

      await coverImages.moveAll(uploadFolder, (file) => {

        let newFileName = `${new Date().getTime()}.${file.subtype}`
        let newFilePath = `images/books/${newFileName}`

        filePaths.push(newFilePath)

        return {
          name: newFileName,
          overwrite: true
        }
      })

      if(!coverImages.movedAll()){
        return coverImages.errors()
      }

      const bookCovers = {
        img_1 : filePaths[0],
        img_2 : filePaths[1],
        img_3 : filePaths[2]
      }

      bookData.cover_images = JSON.stringify(bookCovers);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Your distination directory `F:\nipu\eCommerce\public\images\books\` may not publicly accessible.

**If your distination is publicly accessible,**
Apply this official patch [fix to move the file across devices/drives](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/commit/1e36b4f44ce5dfebc39d46525f52dd2cae2e3439) by upgrading the new version.

This issue is already reported and closed [Here](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/issues/438).

**Take a tour of** [File Upload | Adonis](https://adonisjs.com/docs/3.2/security-introduction#_file_uploads)